# How do you go about refreshing a JWT token whilst iOS Swift app is closed?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, session, jwt

How do apps, like Snapchat/Instagram, keep you logged in even after the app is closed? You won't be able to refresh a close expiring token whilst the app is closed.

What approach would you take when keeping a user's session open with JWT until they effectively log out? I have no clue what Snapchat and Instagram use for authentication, however both of them offer an option to save your username and password so when you log out, you can log back in again without inputting your details in again. So maybe they just save your username and password and use that every time you log into each app?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to refresh the token while the app is inactive. Instead, you can simply save the expiry date in `UserDefaults`, when the user opens the app again check if the expiry date has been over if so refresh the token.

Comment: How would I refresh the token if the token itself is expired? Would I need to use two tokens?

Comment: It depends on how the backend handles token refreshing. Sending the old token to generate a new one is a commonly used pattern.

Comment: How would you go back refreshing tokens if you made your own backend? Either way, if I had a normal token and a refresh token (that will be stored in the secure keychain) if a hacker gains access to one token, they can just as easily get access to the refresh token, so I wouldn't see any point in having two tokens anyway?

Comment: Keychain is a secure place to store the token. You could encrypt the key to add more protection if security and hacks are a big concern. Although these are topics to be discussed in security or encryption related post. Here we're discussing how to handle token refresh when app is closed.

Answer (score -1):

Basically while authentication on login for example

backend will send two types of token one is jwt token and secondly token for generating the new token you might receive new separate api for token generation from the backend